# Difference between 決算書, 財務諸表 and 決算書類

Tags: word-choice

①　What is the difference between 決算書{けっさんしょ},　財務諸表{ざいむしょひょう}　and 決算書類{けっさんしょるい}?
I have a table and they are named there one by one, as if each of them would have different meaning :

> 決算書｛けっさんしょ｝,　財務諸表｛ざいむしょひょう｝　and　決算書類｛けっさんしょるい｝

➁　Do you think I could also translate these 3 terms as below?

> "any financial statements"

Thank you so much in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between 決算書{けっさんしょ}, [財務]{ざいむ}[諸表]{しょひょう} and [決算]{けっさん}[書類]{しょるい}?

決算書{けっさんしょ} and [財務]{ざいむ}[諸表]{しょひょう} are both technical terms with the same meaning.

> 原文 (Wikipedia):
>    **財務｛ざいむ｝諸表｛しょひょう｝**（financial statements）は、企業｛きぎょう｝が利害｛りがい｝関係者｛かんけいしゃ｝に対｛たい｝して一定｛いってい｝期間｛きかん｝の経営｛けいえい｝成績｛せいせき｝や財務｛ざいむ｝状態｛じょうたい｝等｛とう｝を明｛あき｝らかにするために複式｛ふくしき｝簿記｛ぼき｝に基｛もと｝づき作成｛さくせい｝される書類｛しょるい｝である。**一般的｛いっぱんてき｝には決算書｛けっさんしょ｝と呼｛よ｝ばれることが多｛おお｝い。**
>   https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B2%A1%E5%8B%99%E8%AB%B8%E8%A1%A8
>
> Translation:
>   **[財務]{ざいむ}[諸表]{しょひょう}** is the document which is made based on double-entry bookkeeping because a company clarifies business showings of a fixed period of time or a financing state for interested party. **Generally, it is often called 決算書{けっさんしょ}.**

The following infomation is from
https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2674653.html

**[決算]{けっさん}[書類]{しょるい}** is not a technical term but a popular name which refers to documents of settlement of accounts-related accounts and the tax practice generally, and the range of documents is not necessarily clear. Generally it includes following documents:

・貸借対照表
・損益計算書（製造原価明細書、販売費・一般管理費明細書）
・貸借対照表と損益計算書の勘定科目の内訳書
・利益処分案又は株主資本等変動計算書
・法人税確定申告書と付表
・法人住民税、法人事業税、事業所税、消費税の確定申告書と付表

"**財務｛ざいむ｝諸表｛しょひょう｝**（証券｛しょうけん｝取引法｛とりひきほう｝関係｛かんけい｝）" includes:
・貸借対照表
・損益計算書
・株主資本等変動計算書
・キャッシュ・フロー計算書
・附属明細表

Answer (score 1):

① I believe you have the knowledge of accounting. If so, you can look up the Japanese words in Japanese-English dictionary. If you don't have the adequet knowledge, firstly you have to get it.

② I can't understand why you'd like to have one name of three documents.

Anyway "any financial statements" in Japanese is just "全ての財務諸表." If you'd  like to indicate clearly three documents, say "​決算書、財務諸表、決算（付属）書類"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I appreciate it. I am just starting to learn about accounting, so I know still just a little about it. Otherwise, if dictionary had the answer, I would not ask this question. Also 決算書 is often indicated to have the same meaning as the 財務諸表, but I am trying to understand their differences, even they are quite similar. Actually my goal is not how to say "any financial documents" in Japanese, but how should I distinguish the three Japanese therms in case I would translate them in English.